# MPEG-DASH stream never choosing representation with lowest bandwidth

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, mp4box, mpeg-dash

I've converted an mp4 file into four mp4s using ffmpeg: three video-only files of low, medium and high quality, and one with only audio. I then converted these into an MPEG-DASH using MP4Box and hosted it at:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/wst-videostore2-test/dash5/bourne_test_dash.mpd

Even when throttling the connection to the point where the video stops to buffer, the client attempts to download the medium quality representation, rather than the low quality one that has the lowest bandwidth as specified in the MPD file, from having the lowest bitrate used when encoding it with ffmpeg.

I'm new to anything to do with videos so really don't know what's going on. Any help would be much appreciated!